# Inserting newly inserted ID of one table in other table but return the first inserted ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `pages` which has a sub-table called `page_objects`.

Let's say a the tables have the following data:

**pages**

1. page_id - int(6)
2. f_page_object_id - int(6)

**page_objects**

1. page_object_id - int(6)
2. f_page_id - int(6)
3. status - char(1)

One page can have more page_objects, but only one page_object per page is 'active'.

When I insert a new page, I want to directly add a `page_object` also using the created ID of the created `page`.

**1st Question:** Is it possible to do this in 1 query? (e.g. by using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the query for the `page_object`?)

If the above is possible: **2nd Question:** I need to return both ID's of the newly created rows, how do I do this?

**3th Question:** The resulting `page_id` must then be updated in the `page_object, is it possible to do this in one query?

Currently I am using three queries, which imo is not really optimized?
I would like to learn to optimize my MySQL queries, but I am fairly new to it, so any tips/help you can give me is welcome!

Comment: Without seeing the current queries / code we'd have to speculate on if this is really optimal. You might consider creating and calling a stored procedure.;

Comment: 1) Yes - by using last_insert_id(). 2) Yes, by creating a stored proc or at least using variables in an sql script. But you cannot do this in a single sql statement. 3) No, you cannot insert and update in a single query. Create a stored procedure to encapsulate the entire page creation functionality.